# Moving files from various folder in to single folder based on the list

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a relatively simple task to do. I have to move 100 files which are located in various different folders, into one single folder. So far I have the script that will do this if i am moving the files from one folder to another folder based on the list of files.

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\IMAGES_SOURCE
set Target=C:\IMAGE_DESTINATION
set FileList=C:\ImageList.txt
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do copy "%Source%\%%a" 
"%Target%"

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

So for this instance, I created the list of the items and scrip will look for the file name in source location and once find them it will move them to a destination location.

I need to adjust this so it reads the names of the files and try to find them in the list of the folders that they might be.

What i have tried is to change the set Source to be also separate list that will contain posible folder names:

```
set Source=C:\DirList.txt
```

But when i do this it does not copy the images.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm certain that there will be examples on this site of how to locate specific file names within one or more drives or directories. Your script however shows no attempt at performing either of those scenarios which makes your question an off topic script request. Please search, and write a script which attempts to perform the task you want it to do. If that script fails to achieve your goal then post it here as an edit to your question with a full explanation of what happens differently from your intent.

Comment: Compo - i have looked at the stack overflow if someone has done something like this.  And i have attempt several things that include setting a source to be a list of directories that we be looked through. I just edited main question to reflect that. I am unable to get script to read through the folders on that list.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is `dir /S` meaning it will search using the `dir` command. This is untested, but you'll get the idea:

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\Images_source
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%i in (C:\Imagelist.txt) do (
  set var="%%i"
  for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S !var!') do echo copy "%%~fa" C:\Image_Destination
  )
```

For more on the commands I used, try help by running from from commandline `for /?` and `dir /?`

Once confident that it will copy only what you want to copy/move, then remove the `echo` before copy.